# How to find the exact value of an upper bound for an exponential random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose the waiting  time between people entering a store can be modeled by the exponential random variable $X$ with parameter $\lambda=5$. If you use markov's inequality you can find the $P(X\ge 20)$ is $.25$. How would I find the exact value of $P(X\ge 20)$ ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that $P(X \ge 20) = 1 - P(X \le 20)$ and use the CDF of the exponential r.v. Thus your answer is $1 - F_X(20)$ where $X$ is exponential with $\lambda =5$ and $F_X$ is its CDF.

Let's do the computation:

$P(X \ge 20) = 1-F_X(20)= 1 - (1-e^{-(5)(20)})= 1 - 1 + e^{-100}= e^{-100} = 3.72 \times 10^{-44}$

Indeed, this is a very small number. Which makes sense, intuitively. If the parameter $\lambda = 5$ we have that the mean of the r.v. $X$ is $1/5 = 0.2$.

Putting this in words: the mean waiting time between two persons entering the store is 0.2 minutes. What is the probability that we wait TWENTY minutes or more for the next person to enter? (i.e. $P(X \ge 20)$)

It *has* to be very small.

Comment: when i do that I get .018316 which is significantly smaller than .25, is it just a loose bound or did I mess up my math somewhere?

Comment: See improved answer above

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}, $ $\lambda=5$

find $\int_{20}^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx$